# how to trigger checkbox change by clicking on card

Tags: html, angularjs

How can i change checkbox value if I click on card?

```
<input id="{{a.switchID}}" name="value1" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" ng-click="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber,a.switchID,value1)" ng-model="value1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"></input>
<label style="margin-left: -15px;" for="{{a.switchID}}"></label>
<div class="card" ng-click="click(a.switchID)" style="margin:-59px 0px -2px 51px;height:64px;width:100%" ng-class="{'class1': value1 == false,'class2': value1 == true}"> <p style="margin-left:11px;font-size:18px;color:white;margin-top:8px;">{{a.alias}}</p>
    <p style="font-size:16px;color:white;margin-top:8px;margin-right:11px;" class="pull-right">{{stat}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $scope.click(id) method should set the field's ng-model, $scope.value1, to the false value when it's true and vice versa. This can be obtained with the following code :

```
$scope.value1 = 1 - $scope.value1;
```

There are a few other problems with your code, as the fact you use integers in your checkbox but check value1 against booleans in your card's ng-class. The best would probably be to use booleans all along, which would simplify your conditionnals :

```
<input id="{{a.switchID}}" name="value1" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" ng-click="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber,a.switchID,value1)" ng-model="value1"></input>
<label style="margin-left: -15px;" for="{{a.switchID}}"></label>
<div class="card" ng-click="click(a.switchID)" style="margin:-59px 0px -2px 51px;height:64px;width:100%" ng-class="{'class1': !value1,'class2': value1}"> <p style="margin-left:11px;font-size:18px;color:white;margin-top:8px;">{{a.alias}}</p>
    <p style="font-size:16px;color:white;margin-top:8px;margin-right:11px;" class="pull-right">{{stat}}</p>
</div>


$scope.click = function(id) { 
    $scope.value1 = ! $scope.value1;
}
```